# using backgroundworker on load form withaout button click events

Tags: c#

I want to use background worker dynamically on load form without button click events c#

my load form is :

```
    public void FrmListeClient_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            timer1.Enabled = true;
            CnxBase cnx = new CnxBase();
            c1TrueDBGrid1.DataSource = GestionCredit.service.Client.getInstance().GetClient();
            grd_Liste_Credit_Client.DataSource = GestionCredit.service.Client.getInstance().GetCredit();
            cnx.CloseConnection(CnxBase.myConn);

    }
```

Comment: The same way you would from a click event or any other method. A BackgroundWorker has nothing to do wtih button events. Also, please post *relevant* code. Just posting a Load method that has no relation to the question doesn't help at all.

Comment: Please edit your question, don't post your code in the comments. And this code still has nothing to do with a BackgroundWorker

Comment: I repeat, post the code in the question. Don't expect anyone to check the comments and try to decipher the unformatted code. Besides, comments *are* deleted often. SO isn't a discussion forum, it's a Q&A forum so comments on the question don't really help other users. As for your question, why don't you simply call your worker's Run method from Load ?

Comment: I have already done it, thinks you are right

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you use the line

```
timer1.Enabled = true;
```

If your intend is to refresh periodically the data, you should use the Timer event of the timer1 object instead the form_Load. In that case you should to check the `backgroundworker.IsBusy` property to avoid launch two times the same work.

To use the backgroundworker, add a backgroundworker control to your form. Then you can use the DoWork and RunWorkerCompleted events:
Be aware that you can't assign the datasource properties inside the DoWork event because it is executing in another thread and can not interact with user interface

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) {
    CnxBase cnx = new CnxBase();
    Tuple<List<Client>, List<Credit>> result; 
    result.Item1 = GestionCredit.service.Client.getInstance().GetClient();
    result.Item2 = GestionCredit.service.Client.getInstance().GetCredit();
    cnx.CloseConnection(CnxBase.myConn);
    e.Result = result;
}

private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e) {
    Tuple<List<Client>, List<Credit>> result = e.Result as Tuple<List<Client>, List<Credit>>;
    c1TrueDBGrid1.DataSource = result.Item1;
    grd_Liste_Credit_Client.DataSource = result.Item2;
}
```

Comment: thinks for your answer but my Load fram has one paramettre
this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.FrmListeClient_Load);
and i can't use ure code